# Sqlite inner join not working :s

Tags: php, sqlite, select, join

```
SELECT id, subject
FROM pages AS a
INNER JOIN articles AS b ON a.subject = b.id
WHERE a.id = ?
```

It doesn't work, it says:

> General error: 1 ambiguous column name: id.

But I made an alias of table pages (a) and used it in the WHERE clause. Why is it ambiguous then?

Table pages has `id`, `subject` and some other columns. The `subject` column should link to the `id` column of another table, `articles`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use alias before your column names, try to add them

```
SELECT a.id, a.subject 
FROM pages AS a 
INNER JOIN articles AS b 
ON a.subject = b.id 
WHERE a.id = ?
```

Note that using `a.id` you will get `id` column from table `pages`, if you want to get `id` from table `articles` just change to `b.id`

Comment: Now I get "false", but I know there's a record that has the ID of b.subject in the articles table...

Comment: @Anna check carefully, this is the correct syntax, if you have records matching the clauses they will be retuned. Did you change question mark with actual id?